# Анимация при прокрутке RecyclerView вниз

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, прокрутка, android-animation

Использую анимацию при прокрутке `RecyclerView`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

<translate
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"
    />
</set>
```

Запускаю в адаптере ресайкла:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mainActivity, R.anim.up_from_bottom);
holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Анимация работает как положено, однако если я буду скролить вверх, то это получается не совсем красиво, пытался реализовать следующее:

Хотел сделать чтобы при прокрутке вверх айтемы подгружались сверху, при прокрутке вниз как и есть снизу, не смог. Затем попробовал сделать, чтобы при прокрутке вниз была анимация, а прокрутка вверх происходила без анимации, тоже не смог. Собственно устроит один из двух вариантов, если кто знает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант заюзать библиотеку которых много.
[вот например:](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators)

или повесить слушатель скролла вверх - одна анимация, вниз другая

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                    : R.anim.down_from_top);
    holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;
```

Comment: Что-то подобное пытался сделать, `lastPosition` переменная ваша непонятна мне.

Comment: Это сокращенная версия можно сказать оператора if else.

Comment: Ну это я понял, я имею ввиду где и как мне объявить переменную `lastPosition` что она содержит в себе? Я поместил в нее длину массива, но анимация все равно только во дну сторону работает

Comment: private int lastPosition = -1; в шапке. А position приходит в холдере  . И ваи нужно 2 файла анимации. Вниз и вверх

Comment: Работает! Изумительно!